# How to insert muliple rows to an existing table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Hi i am trying to insert 10000 records in to a table, by using this command.

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(
    id            INTEGER      PRIMARY KEY,
    TEXT          INTEGER       NOT NULL,
    OLDID         iNTEGER       NOT NULL,
    Firstname      VARCHAR(50)  NOT NULL,
    Middlename    VARCHAR(50)   NULL,
    last_name     VARCHAR(75)   NOT NULL,
    EMAIL         VARCHAR(225)  NOT NULL,
    STATUS        BOOL          NOT NULL
);

DECLARE @i int
declare @rows_to_insert int
SET @i = 6
set @rows_to_insert = 10000

WHILE @i < @rows_to_insert
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (@i, @i,@i,'john'+@i,null,'Test','john'+@i+'@someone.com','Active');
        set @i = @i+1
    END
```

But i am getting this Error.

> Msg 8101, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
>   An explicit value for the identity column in table 'mytable' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i solve "An explicit value for the identity column in table"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069420/how-can-i-solve-an-explicit-value-for-the-identity-column-in-table)

Comment: Well, the message says it all doesn't it?

Comment: For next time, please use the error message to [search the archives](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[sql]+An+explicit+value+for+the+identity+column+in+table) first. As you would have found an answer to the question in seconds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The table has an identity column.  You need to explicitly state the rest of the columns in the insert statement.  I might assume that your first column is the identity.  Then it would look something like:

```
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO mytable(<col2>, <col3>, <col4>, <col5>, <col6>, <col7>)
        VALUES (@i,@i,'john'+@i,null,'Test','john'+@i+'@someone.com','Active');
    set @i = @i+1
END
```

Of course, where  is you would have your column names.  It is always a good idea to list the column names, by the way.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to insert a value into the identity column.  For example if your table looks like this:

```
Id        | Name    | Value
^identity
```

Then you cannot insert a value into the `Id` column unless you set `IDENTITY_INSERT`.  This would mean that a valid insert statement would look like:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (Name, Value) VALUES ('MyName', 'MyValue')
```

The `Id` would be automatically generated.

Comment: It is a SQL antipattern to omit the column definitions from theinsert part of the statement.

Answer (score 2):

Your table definition is using incremental ID as identity (Primary Key). So you can't insert value for this primary key because the value will automatically inserted.

To resolve your problem, use query template bellow for inserting data and exclude the primary key as it will be automatically inserted:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (field1, field2,...) VALUES (value1, value2...)
```